# Minecraft Plugin how can I fix my Weapon System here?

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft, bukkit

I have a Problem with my Weapon System in my Minecraft Plugin.

```
package me.feist2007.loopcityscript.weapons;

import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.Sound;
import org.bukkit.entity.Arrow;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;

import me.feist2007.loopcityscript.main;
import me.feist2007.loopcityscript.utils.Utils;

public class Pistole extends Weapon{
    static int maxAmmoInClip = 12;
    static int Ammo = 12;
    static int AmmoInClip = 12;
    public Pistole(main plugin, Material material, long reloadTime, double damage) {
        super(plugin, material, reloadTime, damage);

    }


    @Override
    public void shootEffects(Player player) {
        if(this.AmmoInClip > 0) {
        Arrow projectile = player.launchProjectile(Arrow.class);
        projectile.setVelocity(player.getEyeLocation().getDirection().multiply(18));
        projectile.setShooter(player);
    player.getWorld().playSound(player.getLocation(), Sound.ENTITY_IRONGOLEM_HURT, 30, 1);
        this.AmmoInClip = this.AmmoInClip - 1;
    }}


    @Override
    protected void reload(Player player) {
        if(this.Ammo >= this.AmmoInClip) {
            this.AmmoInClip = 12;
            this.Ammo = this.Ammo - 12;
        }

    }


}
```

the Problem is that the Ammo and the reloading counts for all Players on the Server and not only for  one Weapon. Any Idea how I can code it so that the reload and Ammo just counts for one Weapon

Comment: and i have 1 more question: How can i make that when i reload/restart the server it saves the ammo which ist in the weapon?

Answer (score 1):

You are setting `Ammo` and `AmmoInClip` as your class' variables, so any player will be able to change the values. I would recommend you use a `Map<UUID, Integer>` where you can track each player's own unique values. [Also, in Java, variable names are supposed to be lowerCamelCase](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html). I corrected this in the snippet below, as well as show you how to solve your problem using a Map.

```
    private Map<UUID, Integer> ammoInClipMap = new HashMap<>();

    @Override
    public void shootEffects(Player player) {
        int ammoInClip = ammoInClipMap.getOrDefault(player.getUniqueId(), 12);

        if (ammoInClip > 0) {
            Arrow projectile = player.launchProjectile(Arrow.class);
            projectile.setVelocity(player.getEyeLocation().getDirection().multiply(18));
            projectile.setShooter(player);
            player.getWorld().playSound(player.getLocation(), Sound.ENTITY_IRONGOLEM_HURT, 30, 1);
            ammoInClipMap.put(player.getUniqueId(), ammoInClip - 1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the Help. Now it works but when i reload the Server it will reset the Ammo and so on.

Comment: If you want the ammo to be saved on server restarts, you must save it on an external source, such as a file or MySQL database.